# How to create an Angular component that can act as either a Material Dialog or a Material Bottom Sheet, depending on the screen size?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-components, material-dialog

I'm trying to create an Angular component that is a Mat Dialog when the screen is bigger than 500px and Mat Bottom Sheet when the screen is lower.

The following code is just a basic example of the code I have. However, the actual code is much more complex, with hundreds of lines of HTML, SCSS, and JS. I don't want to create two separate components (one as a Mat Dialog and the other as a Mat Bottom Sheet) because they would have almost identical code. Therefore, I am looking for a way to combine both components into a single one.

Dialog/Bottom Sheet Component

```
export interface MyComponentData {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}

@Component({
    selector: "my-component",
    templateUrl: "./my-component.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./my-component.component.scss"]
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public bottomSheetData: MyComponentData,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: MyComponentData,
        public bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<MyComponent>,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>
    ) {}
}
```

Main Component

```
@Component({
    selector: "main-component",
    templateUrl: "./main-component.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./main-component.component.scss"]
})
export class MainComponent {
    constructor(private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet, private dialog: MatDialog) {}

    onClick(temp: MyComponentData): void {
        if(window.innerWidth > 500) {
            this.dialog.open(MyComponent, {data: temp})
        } else {
            this.bottomSheet.open(MyComponent, {data: temp})
        }
    }
}
```

When the screen width is less than 500 pixels, and I try to open it as a bottom sheet, it shows the error message `NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!`. On the other hand, when I try to open it as a dialog, it shows the error message `Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatBottomSheetData!`.

When I remove `public bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<MyComponent>` and `@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public bottomSheetData: MyComponentData` from the constructor, the dialog starts to work. Similarly, if I remove `public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>` and `public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>` from the constructor, the bottom sheet works properly.

Can anyone help me with resolving this issue and getting it to work as expected?

Comment: the error is because you don't import the import `MatBottomSheetModule` (from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet') and the `MatDialogModule` (from '@angular/material/dialog')

Comment: I am importing both a shared module. When I remove `public bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<MyComponent>` and `@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public bottomSheetData: MyComponentData` from the constructor, the dialog starts to work. Similarly, if I remove `public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>` and `public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>` from the constructor, the bottom sheet works properly.